# How to use Bing Maps as a web service?

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-7.1, bing

If i want to use Bing maps as a service in my WP7 mobile App...
I just want to send my location right now and a place where I want to go then the map draw a road between these location.
These location might be so far like two cites or so near like two streets.
If I also want to use ground selection lines to specify locations to go between, Is that possible to be done or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [Bing Maps REST Services API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701722.aspx). You get directions, etc., but since you're using WP7, you might consider using the [Bing Maps SDK for WP7](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers/mobile.aspx).